# What is a minimum deployment target for homekit enabled app?

Tags: ios, homekit

I was wondering what is the minimum deployment target if I want to build a HomeKit based application?

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/homekit Introduced in iOS8.

Comment: Any reason you didn't simply look at the reference documentation for HomeKit to see when it was added?

Comment: @rmaddy I actually checked on the documentation before I asked the question but missed it that it was on the side of the documentation pane. I double checked on it after Larme suggested and there it was on the side. Silly me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference (people coming from Google) the answers are:

- **iOS 8+**
- **tvOS 10.0+**
- **watchOS 2.0+**

Per Apple's [HomeKit documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/homekit).